# file_get_contents turned &lt to < in the textarea

Tags: php, html

Something is strange. I realised that the content of my textarea isn't quit right.
The content is coming form the file_get_contents($file). My file is writing in UTF-8 as all my codes.
So in the nodepade++ I have the code

```
$txt = str_replace('<','&lt',$txt);
```

but in the textarea the &lt turned into <.
This is really not good!
I need some help. THX

Comment: It's OK, cause it is how HTML works. If you want to insert text in HTML as is, do at least `htmlspecialchars((string)$text, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8')` for content.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `htmlentities()` like:

`$str = "<";
echo htmlentities($str);`

Will output `&lt;`

**EDIT** 
You can also use htmlspecialchars as comment described above.

Answer (score 3):

> but in the textarea the `&lt;` turned into `<`. This is really not good!

That's the entire point of `&lt;`. It tells the browser "This is a less than character" instead of "This is the start of a tag".

If you want to display an ampersand followed by `lt;` then you need to use the character reference for an ampersand.

`&amp;` means "This is an ampersand character" instead of `&` which means "This is the start of a character reference".

This:

```
&amp;lt;
```

Comment: Very good in-depth explanation, it did'nt answer the question - how-to-fix- but rather - good-to-know. IMO it is actually very much worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:

```
$content = htmlentities(get_content_files($file));
```

Works fine now.